# Detailed Comparison of ICEfaces vs RichFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, icefaces

I've seen a few very brief comparisons of ICEfaces vs. RichFaces, but has anyone written a detailed comparison of the two frameworks?  I am particularly interested in detailed comparisons of the implementation details of each framework, but I've seen little more than short opinions from people who have only used one of the two.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using RichFaces for about 9 months, and it seems to have a significant set of functionality. We haven't run into many cases where we wish RichFaces did more, and our app is fairly large and enterprisey. Keep in mind that RichFaces (and Faces in general) is a fairly big memory hog.

This is the [demo site](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/treeNodesAdaptor.jsf) my team uses quite a bit (the link will get you around the sign-up page as well).

In general, I think you're going to find a lot of people have only worked with one of the two. What kind of features are you looking for? I think this would spur a 'RichFaces has this...', 'So does IceFaces', etc.

Answer (score 3):

ICEfaces provides more good looking components than RichFaces.
ICEfaces is heavy in memory use than RichFaces.
RichFaces has better AJAX support than ICEfaces.

Finally it depends on your requirement which to use.

I have analyzed both, I am using RichFaces since 6 months.